# Is the behaviour of following expression well defined?

Tags: c, sequence-points, c89

Cosider the sequence points in the following expression

```
i = (++i,i++,i);
```

If I am correct the steps of execution will be as follows:

1)

```
++i, i++
```

2)

```
step1,i
```

3)

```
i = step2
```

For evaluation in step 1, the value of i should be modified only once for the construct to be termed as defined(since after evaluation of comma operator there is a sequence point). But I think it is not the case here. Hence it should be undefined.
Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4176333#4176333). Here the above expression is termed as defined. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Annex C of the C11 final draft: *The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3: [...] Between the evaluations of the first and second operands of the following operators: logical AND && (6.5.13); logical OR || (6.5.14); **comma ,** (6.5.17).* You are missing a sequence point which happens between `++i` and `i++`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `i += 2` instead, and avoid the problem. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson It was about finding the problem which may exist.. And I feel it's good to avoid while knowing what exactly we are avoiding.

Comment: @bubble - I just couldn't resist. :-) We get several questions here every week about `i = i++ + ++i - i--;` and don't see why it is so interesting. If you take code like this to a code review, your boss will hit you over the head anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of the following instruction is well-defined.

```
i = (++i, i++, i);
```

There is indeed a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and the second operands of the comma operator (`,`). The annex C of the standard, although informative, provides a description of the sequence points.

> **C11, Annex C Sequence points**
>
> The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:
>
> — Between the evaluations of the function designator and actual
>   arguments in a function call and the actual call. (6.5.2.2).
>
> **— Between the evaluations of the first and second operands of the following operators: logical AND && (6.5.13); logical OR || (6.5.14);
>   comma , (6.5.17).**
>
> — Between the evaluations of the first operand
>   of the conditional ? : operator and whichever of the second and third
>   operands is evaluated (6.5.15).   — The end of a full declarator:
>   declarators (6.7.6);
>
> — Between the evaluation of a full expression and the next full
>   expression to be evaluated. The following are full expressions: an
>   initializer that is not part of a compound literal (6.7.9); the
>   expression in an expression statement (6.8.3); the controlling
>   expression of a selection statement (if or switch) (6.8.4); the
>   controlling expression of a while or do statement (6.8.5); each of the
>   (optional) expressions of a for statement (6.8.5.3); the (optional)
>   expression in a return statement (6.8.6.4).
>
> — Immediately before a library function returns (7.1.4).    — After
>   the actions associated with each formatted input/output function
>   conversion specifier (7.21.6, 7.29.2).
>
> — Immediately before and immediately after each call to a comparison
>   function, and also between any call to a comparison function and any
>   movement of the objects passed as arguments to that call (7.22.5).